# what is the difference between Struts and Tapestry framework

Tags: struts, tapestry

Can any one explain me the difference between Struts and Tapestry framework or may be the comparison between them?

Regards,
Mahendra Athneria
Mumbai
India

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tapestry tutorial is updated here: http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry-tutorial.html

In terms of differences, they are vast.

Struts is an action-oriented framework; it rounds out a few of the roughest edges of the Servlet API and makes it marginally easier to link Actions (the Struts equivalent of a Servlet) to views (usually JSPs).  However, it leaves all the heavy lifting to you.

Tapestry is a component oriented framework: it does all the heavy lifting. Components mean that Tapestry knows much more about the structure of your application, and can do lots of busy work and plumbing such as figuring out good URLs and responding to them automatically: you just concern yourself with your page classes and methods.  It does tons more besides.

Tapestry does a lot, but also tries to stay our of your way when you don't want it.

Finally, Struts has productivity features that are unmatched anywhere: the best exception reporting for when things go wrong, and live class reloading so that you can change your code and immediately see the change in your browser.

Comment: Or rather, Tapestry is the one that has good exception reporting and live class reloading.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will find an experienced and unbiased developer of both frameworks to give you the answer. I guess you will have to invest some time in getting your hands dirty with both of the frameworks  to get a feeling wheter you like action based or component based approach.

There is a short introduction for Struts developers at [Tapestry old site](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/struts.html) which explains major differences.

Comment: thanks bbcooper for your reply.i think that link would solve my query.

Answer (score 1):

Here you been through the tutorial for each? I would have that would illustrate the differences better than someone trying to explain it:

Tapestry 5:
http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5.1/tutorial1/

Struts 2:
https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/getting-started.html